# Set element height equal to width using Vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, domdocument

I have a Nodelist of 10 elements which I am getting using below:

```
let elements = document.getElementById('all-photos-root').querySelectorAll('.photo-root');
```

This gives me a NodeList with 10 elements. The initial width on each element is set in percentage which is 25%. I want to set the height of each element equal to the width in pixels so that it always renders as a square.

I am doing it like below, but I always get width is undefined.

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log('elements', elements[i], elements[i].style.width);
    elements[i].style.height = elements[i].style.width;
}
```

Comment: Try using [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 5):

Using `Element#style` will only get the properties that have been set inline (the properties in the `style` attribute, properties on the css won't be included).

If you want to get the currently active property you should use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

You can also use `offsetWidth`, `clientWidth` or `scrollWidth` to get the width of the block in pixels (in number format).

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
var fooBar = document.getElementById("foo-bar");

console.log("Foo:");
console.log(foo.style.width); // 30px
console.log(getComputedStyle(foo).width); // 30px
console.log(foo.offsetWidth);

console.log("Bar:");
console.log(bar.style.width); // hasn't been defined using style attribue
console.log(getComputedStyle(bar).width); // 40px as defined in #bar css block
console.log(bar.offsetWidth);

console.log("FooBar:");
console.log(fooBar.style.width); // hasn't been defined using style attribute
console.log(getComputedStyle(fooBar).width); // will actually give the absolute width in `px` instead of the `50%` used in css block
console.log(fooBar.offsetWidth);
```

```css
#bar {
  width: 40px;
}

#foo-bar {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="width: 30px;"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="foo-bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    // width and height in pixels, including padding and border
    // Corresponds to jQuery outerWidth()
    let width = elements[i].offsetWidth;

    // width and height in pixels, including padding, but without border
    // Corresponds to jQuery innerWidth()
    width = elements[i].clientWidth;

    // Need to add the px at the end
    elements[i].style.height = width + 'px';
  }
```